# MySQL query execution takes time with a single large table?

Tags: php, mysql, join, optimization, query-optimization

I have made a scraping script to download information from a certain websites into a database,which is used further for monitoring historic listing information and their aggregate counts.

Here is the structure of the table:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `biz_listing` (
          `id` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
          `lid` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
          `cid` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
          `name` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
          `type` enum('homeservices','restaurants') NOT NULL,
          `location` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
          `businessID` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
          `reviewcount` int(6) NOT NULL,
          `rating` decimal(10,1) NOT NULL,
          `city` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
          `categories` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
          `result_month` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
          `updated_date` date NOT NULL,
          KEY `businessID` (`businessID`),
          KEY `updated_date` (`updated_date`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The script has collected about 3.5 million results so far,but currently due to the large number of records in the table the script is taking large time in query execution and results in time out issues.We have certain queries to make reports based on the results populated.The scraping script is live and is populating results,but currently I cannot make reports based on the aggregate functions.

For reference ,here is the query used for aggregate reports:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(t.`type`) AS count,
COUNT(t.`businessID`) AS bizcount, 
SUM(t.reviewcount) AS reviewcount,
t.`type`,t.`location` as city 
FROM `biz_listing` t 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT `businessID`,count(*) c 
FROM `biz_listing` 
where 
DATE_FORMAT(`updated_date`, '%m %Y') 
BETWEEN '01 2014' AND '02 2014' 
group by `businessID` HAVING c = 2 ) t2 ON t2.`businessID` = t.`businessID` 
where DATE_FORMAT(t.`updated_date`, '%m %Y')= '01 2014' 
and t.type='homeservices' 
GROUP BY t.location, t.result_month
```

**The above query is used to get a location wise report of business listing counts and their review counts. Here the listing shows aggregate report of businesses common on Jan 2014 and Feb 2014 in the database.**

Now query execution from the table **biz_listing** is taking much time and often the process fails.

**EXPLAIN**

[image]

Does storing all the data in a single table is the reason for this ? The current script is set to continue scraping information to the same table itself. I can't bear lose of any data ,also I should make the report making query faster.

In some forums I found that table size is not an issue in these kind of cases and a proper partitioning would help. Since I'm concerned on the data,I'm confused and worried about about making experiments.

Since the table is supposed to have more records later on,does partitioning of table could help me. I got the idea of partitioning just from the reference documents and I confused on how to implement it?

Any suggestions or advise is highly appreciable.I could also provide any supporting information ,if necessary.?

Comment: What is the output of `EXPLAIN <your query>`?

Comment: You shouldn't use `DATE_FORMAT()` in your WHERE clause. Use the plain column `update_date`, so MySQL can use an index.

Comment: That's what I was about to ask : what are your indexes on your table ?

Comment: I find it surprising how you would even think that storing something in a single table might be the culprit and not the fact you wrote the query in such a way that even god himself couldn't use an index there, with all his might and glory.

Comment: @N.B. If I am wrong, could you please help me in correcting them?

Comment: @VMai Actually I have added index to update_date very recently.And the issue exist without an index too . I understand using 'DATE_FORMAT' takes some time in converting but does that create such an overhead?
I added index to update_date inorder to try with MySQL partioning

Comment: The problem is that it forces MySQL to process every single row in the table converting the ~3.5 million update_date values before it can decide if the row is required. Hence the index on update_date is useless for this query. Further, where does result_month come from? It is not in the table you have shown nor is it derived in the query.

Comment: @Kickstart OK.I understand the issue with DATE_FORMAT. And regarding results_month , I had updated the table creation query now.

Comment: You are using results_month in the GROUP BY, but not mentioning it in the actual select. How will you know which results_month a row refers to? Similarly you have a count of t.type but t.type is also brought back as a column. Unless t.type will only have a single value other than NULL this will not be useful (one value of t.type will be brought back, but which one including nulls is not defined).

Comment: @Kickstart I had thoughts in the same line. But `t.type` is restricted to one single value in the outer `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @VMai - yes, in which case the query may as well put t.type in the GROUP BY clause. Also might be worth swapping to COUNT(*) rather than COUNT(t.type) which might perform a bit better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to do is to remove DATE_FORMAT and just check the dates:-

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(t.`type`) AS count,
    COUNT(t.`businessID`) AS bizcount, 
    SUM(t.reviewcount) AS reviewcount,
    t.`type`,
    t.`location` as city 
FROM `biz_listing` t 
INNER JOIN 
( 
    SELECT `businessID`,count(*) c 
    FROM `biz_listing` 
    WHERE updated_date BETWEEN '2014/01/01' AND '2014/02/28' 
    GROUP BY `businessID` 
    HAVING c = 2 
) t2 ON t2.`businessID` = t.`businessID` 
WHERE updated_date BETWEEN '2014/01/01' AND '2014/02/28' 
AND t.type='homeservices' 
GROUP BY t.location, t.result_month
```

Down side of that is you have to specify the last day of the month. You can over come that using LAST_DAY:-

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(t.`type`) AS count,
    COUNT(t.`businessID`) AS bizcount, 
    SUM(t.reviewcount) AS reviewcount,
    t.`type`,
    t.`location` as city 
FROM `biz_listing` t 
INNER JOIN 
( 
    SELECT `businessID`,count(*) c 
    FROM `biz_listing` 
    WHERE updated_date BETWEEN '2014/01/01' AND LAST_DAY('2014/02/01')
    GROUP BY `businessID` 
    HAVING c = 2 
) t2 ON t2.`businessID` = t.`businessID` 
WHERE updated_date BETWEEN '2014/01/01' AND LAST_DAY('2014/02/01')
AND t.type='homeservices' 
GROUP BY t.location, t.result_month
```

Note that as it is acting on a constant LAST_DAY will be execute once for each time in the query rather than once for each row it is checking.

You probably want to add a covering index on type and update_date on the table as well (ie, one index that has both columns). Similarly add an index covering both businessID and update_date.

EDIT

Looking at your query again, it looks like you are looking for matches on a business id one month which has a record on that month and the next month. If I understand what you want each business can only have 1 record each month (hence you counted them over 2 months and used HAVING ...  = 2).

If this is correct then you can maybe do multiple joins, one for each month:-

```
SELECT 
        COUNT(t0.type) AS count,
        COUNT(t0.businessID) AS bizcount, 
        SUM(t0.reviewcount) AS reviewcount,
        t0.type,
        t0.location as city ,
        t0.result_month
FROM biz_listing t0 
INNER JOIN biz_listing t1
ON t0.businessID = t1.businessID
INNER JOIN biz_listing t2
ON t0.businessID = t2.businessID
WHERE t0.updated_date BETWEEN '2014/01/01' AND LAST_DAY('2014/01/01')
AND t1.updated_date BETWEEN '2014/01/01' AND LAST_DAY('2014/01/01')
AND t2.updated_date BETWEEN '2014/02/01' AND LAST_DAY('2014/02/01')
AND t0.type='homeservices' 
GROUP BY t.location, t.type, t.result_month
```

Note, if I have misunderstood and a businessID can have multiple records each month the this will not work.

Comment: Thank for this. I tried using this method and got the results.But still the time taken is not very commendable :(
I tried your query with my local copy of database which consist of just about 1 million records.I used two covering indexes suggested and tried the query.It took about 15 seconds to execute.
Will this work with my actual data set consisting of 3.5 million records ,which will further increase at least .5 million per month.

Comment: Roughly how many businessID are there? MySQL is quite poor at using sub queries (in effect it ignores the indexes when joining a sub query). It is possible that the sub query itself is what is slowing things down, but I can't see any obvious way to avoid using it (beyond having a temp table populated by the sub query first, then using that temp table rather than the sub query in this query).

Comment: Currently my table consist of 3.5 million records and its expected to add .5-.6 million additions to the table every month. I haven't worked with temp tables,if that do some considerable changes  I am quite interested to it.

Comment: But how many businessID are there? Is that (say) 7 businessID each with 0.5m records, or 3.5m businessID each with 1 record?

Comment: I am getting businessIDs as response from scraping.We will get approximately .5-.6 million unique businessIDs every month.As in my question,its a data warehouse where details of businesses are updated monthly.(each business with corresponding businessIDS)

Comment: In which case the sub query will probably cause a major problem. I will have a think, but not sure how much can be done without a major table redesign.

Comment: I need to take care of the data within and I am even ready for a table redesign if it could help in a long term.

Comment: Added a suggestion, based on my guess as to the data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56890/discussion-between-surabhil-and-kickstart).

Answer (score 1):

please create index for your database table on `updated_date` and `type` columns,it will help to execute your query  as fast